# Flurry App Circle: getHook returning null?

Tags: android, flurry

I'm trying to implement Flurry's App Circle SDK into my Android app.

I have written a function to return a banner view that I will display elsewhere:

```
private ViewGroup getAppCircleView(){

    Log.i(TAG,"Cached Offers: " + appCircle.getAllOffers().toString());

    View ad = appCircle.getHook(this, "listEditor", com.flurry.android.Constants.MODE_PORTRAIT);
    if(ad == null)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "getAppCircleView returned null");
        return null;
    }

    FrameLayout fl = new FrameLayout(this);
    fl.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    fl.addView(ad);

    return fl;
}
```

There are two problems I'm not sure how to solve.

1. appCircle.getAllOffers() returns an empty list, indicating that Flurry hasn't downloaded any ads to display.
2. `View ad = appCircle.getHook(this, "listEditor", com.flurry.android.Constants.MODE_PORTRAIT);` always results in `ad` being null.  Shouldn't a default textview be returned with the "No Ad Available" message?

Answer (score 0):

If getAllOffers returns null I can think about 2 things:

you did not enable appCircle:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FlurryAgent.enableAppCircle();
    FlurryAgent.onStartSession(this, "your_key");
}
```

you might need to pass an hookname when you get the offers:

```
appCircle.getAllOffers("hookName");
```

Anyway keep in mind that flurry goes up and down a lot, sometimes they have lots of ads to show, sometimes nothing...which sucks

Comment: 10 minutes after posting, it just worked.  I'm guessing it's that up and down thing.  I tied it in through adwhirl though so it's not too bad.

Comment: Cool. Yeah, it makes sense to use it with adwhirl